# Can anyone tell me whats wrong here in this simple code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, serverside-javascript

#### (server-side)

```
const express = require('express');

//instance of an app
const app = express();
//middleware
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.json());
//core package to let the server and client side talk without any security boundaries

const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.static('node'));

//setting up server

const port = 8000;
const server = app.listen(port, listenning);
function listenning(){
    console.log(`running on local server: ${port}`);
};

//GET route

const data = [];

app.post('/addMovie', addMovie)

function addMovie(req, res){
    data.push(req.body);
    console.log(data);
};
```

#### (client-side)

```
const postData = async(URL='', data= {})=>{
    console.log(data);

const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'post',
    credentials: 'same-origin',

    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
});

try{
    const newData = await response.json();
    console.log(newData);
    return newData
}catch(error){

    console.log("error", error);

}
}

postData('/addMovie', {movie: 'Dark Knight', score: 5});
```

I'm making a simple POST request via node.js and express but can't find what is wrong, here is the code, when i load the page it says "cannot GET" and gives that error " 404 (Not Found)"
can anyone help ??

Comment: What do you set in your `url` variable?

Comment: A 404 error indicates that the server itself was found, but that the server was not able to retrieve the requested page

Comment: In other words, it means the URL was wrong.

Comment: u mean in this line  "app.post('/addMovie', addMovie)" ?

Comment: '/addMovie' is the address being sent complete

Answer (score 0):

Error `404` means the URL is wrong.

You pass `'/addMovie'` as URL, and use it for fetch.

You might want to update this:

```
const response = await fetch(url, {
```

to this

```
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000' + url, {
```

By adding `'http://localhost:8000'` as prefix of your url.

Comment: I just tried but nothing happened the problem still exists !

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should `POST` to the endpoint:

```
http://localhost:8000/addMovie
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

@Balastrong's answer is the most correct (you need to use `http://localhost:8000` as your base URI), but you'll also need to update your parameter name for your `postData` function. Right now `URL` is capitalized, but your use of the variable later on is all lower case.

So use `const postData = async(url='',`